# 2 none nested model in 1 form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does any one know how to make 2 none nested models work on a single form for rails 4? For example, I have user model that has one profile(model) and one car(model).

Both profile and car models are nested under user but car and profile has no relationship. I figure I can do a form_for user and use both field_for profile/car but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would create a form object.  Check out point '3. Extract Form Objects' in the following post: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/